# How to do circular and complex navigations?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

In my program have 6 view controllers.(in storyboard)
Lets define 1,2,3,4,5,6.

1 is my main view.

I want to navigate like this(image bellow).Is it possible to do?
give me a idea to do this navigation.

[image]

Comment: This is a regular navigation scheme. Use UINavigationController.

Comment: Use self.navigationController pushViewController, popViewController, popToViewController

Comment: Hi beryllium.
Thanks for the quick response. could you please explain what mentioned ? We are using Storyboard with Mode View Controllers. But having a big problem, after some time it takes huge memory and application i getting crash. So I am looking for a best option to handle a complex navigation as I mentioned above. If you can give a sample, that will be great.

Comment: @pubudu, you have to use popViewController, popToRootViewController methods to avoid collecting all the controllers into one stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, u can implement this. This is a simple navigation in iOS using NavigationController.
you have six viewControllers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.

to do this:
First create a NavigationController and initialize it with ViewController 1 (ie a root View Controller).

Now your navigationController behaves like a stack which contains all ur pushed view controller. NavigationController is only push and pop ur view controllers.

So, every time when u want to navigation first check ur viewController is inside navigationController stack or not. If it is already in stack then pop to that controller, if not then push the same view controller.
for this use following:

In case ViewController3

```
-(void)popToSelectedViewController
{
    NSArray *vc=[self.navigationController viewControllers];

    ViewController3 *vc3=nil;

    for (int i=0; i<[vc count]; i++)
    {
        UIViewController *tempVC=[vc objectAtIndex:i];
        if([tempVC isKindOfClass:[ViewController3 class]])
        {
            vc=[vc objectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }

   if(vc3)
    {
       //If exists inside stack the pop
         [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
    }
   else
   {
        //If not exists inside stack push ViewController3
        ViewController3 *vc3New= [[ViewController3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3New animated:YES];
         [vc3New release];
   }


}
```

For initializing ur ViewController1  with navigationController:

**if using storyboard**
Embed ur initialViewController(ie viewController3) with UINavigationController.
for this:

Step1: open storyboard, and select ur initialViewController(ie viewController3).

Step2: Go to Editor in menu -> Choose Embed In -> Select UINavigationController.
this creates a navigationcontroller and initializes with viewController3 as rootViewController.

**if not using storyboard**
make property of vc3 (ViewController3) and applicationNavigationController (UINavigationController) in .h

and in .m:

got method "application... didFinishedLaunching...." in appDelegate
and write:

```
self.vc3=[[ViewController3 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController3" bundle:nil];
    self.applicationNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.vc3];
  self.window.rootViewController=self.applicationNavigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: can you give me some example?
I have problem with
First create a NavigationController and initialize it with ViewController 1

Comment: r u using storyboard?

Comment: Thank you very much @Satish Azad this is very useful for me.that means I no need to prepareForSegue and [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"linktoviewmeetingitem" sender:tableView];like this navigations.

Comment: it not working Satish Azad.
i put your function in my button action in VC1 (to navigate VC2).after that comming this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791724/uinavigationcontroller-pushviewcontroller-error
please comment for this.

Comment: r u using storyboard?

Comment: yes i use storyboard.i fixed that error using ViewControllerSearch *vc3New = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcsearch"];

this code.

my new error is when i move CV1 to CV2 memory increasing.it ok we dont have CV2 in navigationController. after that when i move to VC2 to CV1.it not memory increasing.but again i move to CV1 to CV2.only one object in navigationController.so again memory increasing.after 2 ,3 time do this thing.my application crashing.why navigationController ressiting.

Comment: after pop,it don't remove from memory.memory always increasing when move to vc1 to cv2.how can i reduced memory.

Comment: can u paste ur some code or what gdb gives error at the time of crashing?

Comment: here i describe my error  Satish Azad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804485/memory-increasing-when-navigation-never-decreasing-how-can-i-decrease-when-pop-u

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40608/discussion-between-satish-azad-and-pubudu)

Answer (score 1):

First You create a navigation controller object

```
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navCtrl;
```

If you want to go to 1->2,1->3,1->6,etc, create an object for the next viewcontroller and push it to navigation stack

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:second animated:YES];
```

You dont need to do any additional work to go back to the previous view controller. The default back button lets you go back.

If you need to return to the root view controller, then use this:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

if you want to return to any particular view controller, then use this

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How can i move to 3->5  ?

Comment: just create an object of 5 from 3 and push that object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UINavigationController`.It is nor circular.It can be assumed as stacked approch.That is what navigation controller do

[A must read for you](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html)