# UINavigationController , pushViewController Error

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have 2 view controller

VC1   has button

in this button action

```
   - (IBAction)clickSearch:(id)sender
{
 NSArray *vc=[self.navigationController viewControllers];

    ViewControllerSearch *vcSearch=nil;

    for (int i=0; i<[vc count]; i++)
    {
        UIViewController *tempVC=[vc objectAtIndex:i];
        if([tempVC isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerSearch class]])
        {
            vcSearch=[vc objectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if(vcSearch)
    {

        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vcSearch animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {

        ViewControllerSearch *vc3New= [[ViewControllerSearch alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewControllerSearch" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3New animated:YES];
        vc3New = nil;
    }

}
```

ViewControllerSearch id my second view controller.these two view s connected with push segue.

when i click the button coming this error.

```
    Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Ravi/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/42268111-F290-40B8-B893-4649852F762C/coffee break app.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewControllerSearch''
```

how can i fixed this error?please give me idea.

Comment: It can't find the 'ViewControllerSearch'.

Comment: try to set the File´s owner of the Nib to ViewControllerSearch

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain your Nib is called 'ViewControllerSearch.xib'?

Also you don't need to nil out vc3New - in fact you probably shouldn't.

UPDATED

...to load from a storyboard, as mentioned in the comment, you need to do something like this:

```
UIStoryboard* storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 
ViewControllerSearch* controller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerSearch"];
```

1) Make to sure the storyboard identifier matches what you've named it
2) Make sure you've set/used the correct identifier, in the storyboard, for your controller

Comment: it is in storyboad.not a xib

Comment: That's probably your issue. You have to use a method on the storyboard to manually create the storyboard based VC. You can't just directly alloc init it.

Comment: Thank you very much.yes it is identifier issue.It fixed usig this code.`ViewControllerSearch *vc3New = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcsearch"]; `