# Memory increasing on navigation, never decreasing. How can I decrease when view controller is popped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my program I have six view controllers. To navigate among these view controllers I used UINavigationController.

I will explain this issue using two view controllers.
In first view controller, I implemented a button action like this

```
- (IBAction)clickSearch:(id)sender{

    [self gotoSearch];
}  

-(void)gotoSearch

{

    NSArray *vc = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
    ViewControllerSearch *vcSearch = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < [vc count]; i++)

    {
        UIViewController *tempVC = [vc objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([tempVC isKindOfClass:[ViewControllerSearch class]])

        {
            vcSearch = [vc objectAtIndex:i];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (vcSearch)

    {
        //If exists inside stack the pop
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:vcSearch animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        //If not exists inside stack push ViewController3

        ViewControllerSearch *vc3New = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vcsearch"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3New animated:YES];
        vc3New = nil;
    }
}
```

second view controller has a button and that button action is also implemented as above.

if I move to second view controller from first view controller ,memory increasing.(its ok)

if I move to first view controller from second view controller, memory level not changing.

again I move to second view controller from first view controller ,memory increasing.you can see it in this image.

(memory is not reducing)How can I reduced memory?
[image]

first time first to second : NSArray *vc has one object (first VC)

second to first : NSArray *vc has two object (first VC,and second VC)

now im in first view controller.now im click to move second view controller : NSArray *vc has only one object (first VC).second vc missing.and increasing memory (i think it for new second vc)

Comment: just do one thing NSLog every time NSArray *vc=[self.navigationController viewControllers];
and check what it has in stack in each navigation

Comment: Also check all delegates which you have declared. Their property should be weak.

Comment: I edit it in my question Satish Azad

Comment: @Satish Azad i add NSArray description.bellow the image in my question.